# What do I need to build simple 3d editor that Ray Tracing 3d images

Tags: c++, 3d

What do I need to know and what libraries do I need to use if I like to 
build simple 3d editor ( like Xara3d for example ) that lts me edit simple 3d objects 
and the end result will produce me good quality Ray Traced image .
simplicity in mind I will use any free lib that abstract and ease the learning curve .
in c++

Comment: I strongly recommend back-ray-tracing. (forward raytrace is better quality if coded properly but extremly slow) and if you want proper outdoor lighting effects (like light gaps) then Only Volumetric renders can do that properly. I do not use any 3th party libs (code renders myself) so I cannot help with lib, but first valid hit on google seems to be this: https://developer.nvidia.com/optix (nvidia is the leader for OpenGL anyway so take a look hope it does not need some special HW like some of their renders do)

Answer (score 3):

Get familiar with Op[enGL](http://www.opengl.org/). Checkout [the many](http://www.fltk.org/) [C++ GUI toolkits](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/11/10/qt3d-features-in-qt-46/) that have excellent support for 3D rendering, which is usually built on top of OpenGL. If the abstractions they provide does not meet your requirements, look at [C++ libraries](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/higherlevel/) that provide better abstractions.

Also see:

- The [Open Scene Graph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) project
- A [list of C++ game engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines).

Comment: well i know all the libraries you offered they are great for the modeling part , now i just wander how can i get the best rendering image quality out of the models , is there some kind of rendering engine i can use .

Comment: i just edit the port the main term is Ray Tracing the 3d objects to images